# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://math.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

<sub>(Answers posted to this announcement should consist of questions for the nominees and general commentary - use separate posts for questions on the election process, suggestions, concerns, and bug reports.)</sub>

Comment: I live in Asia(Taiwan). From time to time, I have seen bad things happen on Math SE and were taken care of much later because of time zone. I am hoping somebody in Asia can watch this forum for us(not me, I am not qualified). How do we find such person and nominate him/her? Should I ask this question in a separte question tagged election?

Comment: People thinking of questions to ask the candidates might want to take a look at previous threads for inspiration.

Comment: @TheChaz: I've added a bit of clarifying text. Posting an answer here effectively addresses all the candidates (no one owns this question). Post a separate question to begin a tangential discussion, raise concerns, or report bugs.

Comment: @TheChaz Update your bookmarks - Stack Exchange has provided us with some hosting: http://elections.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think scaaahu has a good point that it would be nice to have the moderators spread out a bit over different time zones.

Comment: @scaaahu:  There is now a candidate (Benjamin Lim) who lives in Australia.

Comment: On that note: it would be quite nice if the prospective nominees can mention their timezones and how often they visit the site in their nomination text...

Comment: @J.M. I did the latter, will add the former.

Comment: @TaraB, I think it would be very painful for a moderator to spread out over different time zones.

Comment: @Gerry: I believe that's why Tara judiciously chose to use the plural. ;)

Comment: I agree with the reasoning that ideally moderators should come from a wider range of time zones. OTOH some of them may be 24/7 addicts, so it doesn't necessarily matter much :-)

Comment: @TaraB Indeed I am able to cover the asia pacific region. I have commented on Willie's post below too about this.

Comment: Are candidates supposed to answer the questions here (as in, the 'answers' to this 'question') in the comments, or by editing their proposal?

Comment: Wish you all good luck.

Answer (score 10):

**Question to Moderator Candidates: In Which Time Zone are you?**

A very pragmatic question that scaaahu [raised in the comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/2012-community-moderator-election#comment15393_4075) is that our current set of moderators all live in (if I am not mistaken) the narrow band of time zones between UTC+2 and UTC-8. In particular, we have no one covering the "Asian-Pacific region".

The question to the candidates/nominees, should they choose to answer it, is

> In which time-zone are you active*?

`*` It would be most helpful if you factor in your sleep/awake hours. Namely if you live in London but work nights and so get up at 2pm local, you put down something more like UTC-7.

Comment: I fit the status quo, unfortunately. I'm in UTC-5, US East Coast.

Comment: I am UTC +10, so I should be able to cover the asia pacific region. Besides during 2pm - 6pm local time here (UTC +10) I have no classes.

Comment: I disagree on the relevance of this.  There was a thread about this recently; I think on English.SE.  The point was made that even within a time zone, there are people who use SE in the morning, others who log in in the evening, and some who are here in the wee small hours.  So having moderators from multiple time zones is no more beneficial than having a number of moderators in the same time zone.

Comment: @David: I disagree with that. If you have seven moderators which are active at the same time (say, 10am-10pm of some timezone) then you have twelve more hours without real-time moderator response. It is often not the worst thing that could happen, but there might be rare cases where a real-time intervention is required.

Comment: @Asaf: David's point is that being in the same time zone is no guarantee that moderators are active at the same time. The actual habits of the individuals are far more important than the time zones in which they live. Willie's might better have asked when the individual candidates expect to be actively available; their time zone of residence is a proxy, but possibly not a very good one.

Comment: @Brian: Are we looking at the same question? Mine reads "*In which time-zone are you active*" and requests to factor sleeping patterns and actual activity hours in...

Comment: @Asaf: Ignore the last sentence of my comment: I remembered only the question proper, in which *are active* can easily be understood as *reside* (at least by a native speaker), and forgot that Willie had in fact addressed the real issue in the expansion below it.

Comment: My observation is: during UTC time 06:00-08:00, the traffic volume on Math SE is very low. I believe most people are in bed or not log in to our site except the people in pacific region. I was more worried about spams than anything else.

Comment: My time zone is UTC+03:30.

Comment: Though I have added it in my nomination passage, i think i must add it here as well, my time zone is UTC + 5:30

Answer (score 10):

I see that out of the current candidates only two have $>50$ many helpful flags, and only one has the Deputy badge.

In my eyes flagging is the way for non-moderators help with moderation. It seems to me as intriguing why most candidates wish to "take a leap" from zero to a full-time moderation job.

Furthermore, flagging a lot helps the flagging user shape some idea about the fine-structure of the content boundaries of the website, or on CW

> 1. **(To those whose flag weight is less than $50$)** In all the time active on the site, why did you not raise many flags? How do you think you will handle this shift from not-flagging to clear flags?
> 2. **(To all)**  What is your stand on the CW policy? Do you agree or disagree that most big list and soft questions should be turned CW?

Comment: I consider the number of flags virtually irrelevant as a measure of a candidate's qualifications. Dealing with flags is not the same as raising them. Frankly, I'd be more worried about a candidate with a history of raising *lots* of flags, as I favor keeping moderation to a practical minimum.

Comment: @Brian: I agree that it is not *very* relevant. I also strongly agree that minimal moderation is often better than highly intervening one. However there are still *a lot* of posts that require handling, and there are many flags which are essentially unjustified and should be rejected. I wonder how people unexperienced with knowing what to flag are going to handle this task.

Comment: I don't see why you assume that not flagging means that one doesn't know what to flag or, more important, what *not* to flag. I've almost never flagged simply because I've very seldom seen anything that I thought warranted flagging. Closing, yes; flagging, no.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: And are you running for moderator? :-)

Comment: Not at the moment. But what I said may well apply to one or more announced candidates. Whether it does or not, the possibility has to be considered and tends to undermine the notion that number of flags raised is a useful measure of ability to handle flags.

Comment: @Brian: Flagging is not only when there is spam. It is also when someone posts a comment to another answer as an answer; when unregistered accounts need to get merged; etc. I expect moderators to be able to identify such posts on their own as well. I also expect them to be able to judge correctly when an account needs to be merged, or deleted, or so on. This sort of experience is bought in flags.

Comment: Asaf, I know all of this. I still don't agree with your last sentence.

Comment: @Brian: At least until I gain control of nuclear weapons the internet is going to stay a free place. You are entitled to your opinion, and until I can force the fact "You are wrong" to be true, your opinion remains valid. Let us revise this discussion once my plans are complete. <Maniacal laughter here>

Comment: Flagging works when something needs moderator attention, but high-rep users normally have everything under control by announcing a case in the chat room and others follow them. Except merging account which I wouldn't do as a normal user, digging profile to find out who is registered/ unregistered and which accounts need to be merged.

Comment: @Gigili: From my experience the high-rep "control" is for closing questions and occasionally killing spam. Moderator attention is needed for other things as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I know but I was referring to what you listed above as what flags are useful for. Recently, a moderator is available in the chat room so he'll have the rest under "control". I barely see something flag-worthy on the main site.

Comment: @Gigili: If you don't see the flag worthy things *now*, how will you see them when you are a moderator? Do you think that moderators should skip on merging accounts and removing comment-answers posted due to split accounts? If you think the answer is no, what is the difference between acting on that as a moderator and flagging that as a user?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: My point is, as a moderator, I rather go through flags than flagging (Why would I flag something for my own attention?) A moderator point of view is totally different from a normal user, moderators should definitely do merge accounts and remove comment-answers which I wouldn't do as a regular user. Well. flagging those as a user needs a high percent of activity on the main site which I'd admit I haven't had recently. I registered 11 months ago redirecting here from another SE site and wasn't that active except when I had a question!

Comment: I'm familiar with moderator tools since I was one of the top users on German Language and usage, but due to some events I deleted my account.

Comment: @Gigili: Is my bad Mediterranean English a trouble for you to understand what I am trying to say? Why would any moderator flag anything? I'm not even sure they *can*. I can testify that my experience with flags slowly made me quicker to notice when accounts need to be merged, when answers should be turned into comments, and when people are just writing low-quality stuff. What you are saying in your above comments reads to me as: *I do not wish to go through all the posts, but just through those others have flagged, although I did not bother to make the life of current moderators this easy.*

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Perhaps it's my Amzonian English. To address your concern, I believe I can testify about answers which are written as comments or low quality stuff and other things as well. but I felt like a new user on the main site as I don't have much rep due to inactivity. It wasn't a matter of the greatest importance to me, I'd admit again.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is there any way to bully you into nominating yourself as a moderator? Mainly, so you you don't substitute by running for a political office in which you have access to nuclear weapons.

Comment: @Michael: Well, you can always force this option and leave me no choice. If you are willing to assume large enough cardinals then everything definable from things which are real is determined, then you just need to verify that the game we are playing is not one where I have the winning strategy! :-) *[Right now, however I should be getting busy with writing my thesis and expanding my knowledge about forcing... so no way for me to join this round of elections.]*

Comment: @Asaf: Let's hope your thesis is not on "Forcing heathens to disappear for Large Cardinals: My plan to rearm the Vatican with nuclear weapons."

Comment: @Michael: My current working title is "Consistency results regarding vector spaces and limited choice principles". If I won't find a hilarious title to go by I might consider taking this idea of yours and incorporate it into my work somehow!

Comment: @Asaf: 1. Perhaps the topics or questions I've chosen to answer are atypical in that they don't attract the type of responders that require flagging. I have not come across answers or comments myself that I've thought required flagging. Although I have no 'helpful flags', when I've noticed low-quality or duplicate questions, or they are brought to my attention, I have voted to close or delete where appropriate.  To me, this is closer (than flagging) to one of the responsibilities of a moderator: taking action when others point out problems.

Comment: @Asaf: 1. (continued) When I have come across wrong or low-quality answers, rather than downvoting or flagging, I have commented to point out the error or weakness, and tried to offer suggestions for improvement where I could. In my opinion, this helps to produce better answers than simply flagging.

Comment: @Asaf: 2. Most big-list and soft questions are more survey than research, and for this reason, I would say that most should probably be CW. This is not to say that they are without value; some big-list and soft questions have inspired insightful and interesting answers. I am afraid that setting *all* big-list and soft questions to CW might reduce the number of good big-list and soft questions along with the bad.

Comment: @Asaf: FWIW: it is possible for moderators to flag stuff (possibly so we can notify other mods? I am not sure.) But I also know that the "nuclear option" of the closing-vote also applies to SPAM and Offensive flags of Mods, so it is a bit pointless for Mods to flag such content when they can also just hit "delete" (one fewer mouse click).

Comment: We mods *can* flag things. Spam or offensive flags take effect immediately, and all other types are just queued as normal flags. (It could be used as a way for mods to communicate)

Comment: I sort of see the point raised by @Brian that a person flagging continuously would be a bad choice. But the statistics given to us lists **helpful** flags. Surely frivolous flagging would be frowned upon by the mods, and not marked helpful! I see this piece of statistics as a very good indicator of a nominee's ability to work together with the existing team of moderators. In addition to showing that the nominee understands what is to be flagged.

Comment: But I do accept @robjohn's position as well. Also, some tags may be more prone to have posts worthy of a flag than others. If those tags are not a nominee's cup of tea, s/he may not see much to flag.

Comment: @Jyrki: That's a fair point, and it's likely that I'd agree with many, even most, of the helpful flags, given that I've been generally satisfied with the current moderators. But I've a very strong preference for minimal moderation, and that informs the partly visceral reaction that I mentioned in the earlier comment.

Comment: @Jyrki: Of course that I did not mean that any user of the current candidates are serial-no-good-flaggers which flag every post they see but hardly have helpful flags marks. Instead I was implying that most of the candidates are *not* flagging at all, or very very little. As for the point about tags, about 50% of the flags I raise come from the Review page of the Moderation Tools page. Most of my flags are helpful (and like 50+ "disputed" from invalidating other flags).

Comment: @Asaf, it seems to me that we are mostly in agreement! I have myself flagged less than ten times, and I think all of them were judged to be helpful. The Review page is open to only 10k+ users, so lower rep candidates don't have that opportunity. Before I reached that milestone, I only flagged for technical problems: TeX-output running into the margins, a fellow forumite going accidentally over the ten edit limit and such. None of that happens too frequently. So while I agree that helpful flags are helpful, and a good thing on a candidates CV, they are not a **must**.

Comment: cont. FWIW I upvoted this answer. A valid concern, and a question I would like to see the candidates to address.

Comment: @Jyrki: I believe that the review page is accessible for lower reputation as well, the mod. tools page is for 10k+ users. And yes, I do agree and I said it before - raising a lot of helpful flags is not a must, but certainly a big plus for me.

Comment: @All: I flag stuff all the time, whenever I come across something. Well, perhaps all the time is too much - I suppose if we average it, I do roughly 1 flag every 3 days. Is that very much? I would suspect there is more questionable content than that, and I read an awful lot of the content here. I can't expect the moderators to read absolutely everything. In fact, since I've typed this comment, 8 new things happened on the main page (so firefox says). The most important 'moderators', in my opinion, are the standard users of the community. $\diamondsuit$-mods just add a bit of order.

Comment: @All(2): With respect to CW, I like how MSE currently runs. I think it's interesting that we have retained a distinct CW policy from the rest of the SE sites, likely due to our affinity with MO. I think it was Atwood himself who once descended from the Overflow-heavens to say that he thought that MSE could handle CW and soft questions due to the large number of 'real' or 'hard' questions we get. I think I largely agree with Atwood on this point (not with everything). I would be saddened if every question were soft, but they aren't and they won't be. So I believe in them. But I also believe...

Comment: ...(continued) that big-list or very soft questions should be CW in general. This isn't a hard line. It's like trying to define math: I can't really do it, but I know it when I see it. And fortunately, usually people from the communnity (i.e. not official mods) call out that something should or shouldn't be CW, and I like the current way we deal with such questions.

Comment: I'm with Brian on this. Flagging plays almost no role in my evaluation of candidates. To me the primary criterion is who can be the most effective in solving the major issues challenging the site (cf. my comments in the election chat and elsewhere here).

Comment: @Bill: Since you entered the competition, let us (for a brief moment) forget that there are other candidates. Would you answer my question as a candidate? (I especially would like to hear your answer because you once said that you almost never visit threads that you don't answer, which makes a peculiar habit for a moderator).

Comment: @Asaf That was not the "habit of a moderator" but rather, the habit of a teacher. Obviously one adjusts one's actions based upon the hat one wears.

Comment: @Bill, you'd like to think so. However history taught us that in most cases one is wearing one hat and simply say it is a different hat. You're still not answering my question.

Comment: @Asaf My intent is to answer the questions as time appears, prioritized by what I believe are the most important to the evolution of the site. Please be patient.

Comment: @Bill I know it's moot but I'd still like an answer.

Comment: @Asaf As for CW, I haven't thought deeply about it, but generally I lean toward policies that reward contributions.

Answer (score 8):

> 1. How much time do you have to spare and have you thought about whether you are really willing to continue this effort over a long time period?
> 2. What is your stance on "answers in comments" that leave lots of unanswered questions and their flip-side, the "incomplete hint answers"?
> 3. Have you looked at the behaviour and style of the current moderators and do you think that you could cooperate well with them?

Comment: 1. I have been spending several hours a day on Q&A and chat. I don't see any reason why that would change.

2. If an answer is given in a comment that looks acceptable, I would suggest, in a comment to the commenter, that it be added it as an answer. If they don't add it as an answer in a reasonable time (a few days), I see no difficulty adding the answer as CW.

3. The moderators I have dealt with seem quite amicable; I don't think I would have any difficulty working with them.

Comment: 1. As I said in my nomination, My job is such that I need to be online.  Consequently, I'm nearly always online and available, except when I'm eating or sleeping of course.
2.  If I think a comment answers a question, and I see no reason for it not to be an answer, I'll convert it to an answer immediately.  Otherwise, I'll inform the commentator or leave the comment alone.

Comment: 3.  I know Mariano from chat, but I don't think I'm the kind of person who has difficulty communicating with people, especially well-educated people such as the Stack Exchange moderators.

Comment: Do the current moderators convert people's comments to answers without asking them first?  I would consider that much too strong an intervention.

Comment: Also, the problem with "answers in comment" is, usually people tend to do so because they want to see other users' reaction to their comment then they are more willing to post it as an answer. Who finds earning reps annoying?

Comment: I am not sure a moderator can convert comments into answers. However I am sure, the other way around is possible? Will some moderator shed some light?

Comment: We do convert answers into comments: I have only done this in cases where it was obvious that the user was really trying to ask for amplifications on some other user's answer, or on the question itself, or obviously *not* anwering the question nor giving a hint or anything—except for a couple of cases in months, I have only done this in response to not-an-answer flags (but I do not always react to not-an-answer flag in this way). I am pretty sure the other mods follow the same standard here.

Comment: Dar Phira, your point 2 does not so much pertain to what moderators do, but what *users* do: IMO it is users who should suggest those that leave answers as comments to turn them into full answers, and authors of too-partial-hints to expand on them so that they become more generally useful. I will not intervene in such situations with my mod hat unless there is an actual problem.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I don't think that your stance (it is the users' job to flag this) can be just assumed for the candidates I am asking. It is also not clear that they will react in the same way to flags as you do. Read what Gigili answered to question 2 if you think that your answer is a given.

Comment: I have read it, and other things related to this, and I am pretty sure that my stance is **not** a given! :) In fact, several of the nominees seem to view the role of mods to be closer to that of «curators» or «editors» of the site—I am of quite the opposite view. Even before becomign a mod I preferred to leave a comment on a question suggesting that the author fix something than actually fixing it myself (and this is, in general, more work for me than the alternative!) It is more instructive, I think, to point to a typo on a title suggesting that it be fixed than fixing it myself :)

Comment: @Gigili, sorry but I find your comment *...usually people tend to do so because they want to see other users' reaction to their comment...* actually a bit offensive. There are several of us college/university level teachers here. Many of us give "answers in comments" for the sole purpose to give extensive hints and try to teach the original poster to see the light him/herself. This is not a perfect approach on a Q&A forum, but it is the best we can do. I feel that the keen student's interests are best served this way. If you think that we do it to "test waters" that makes me very sad.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I know there are college level teachers here as well students. It was my observation, not a long ago (yesterday) someone posted a comment and when it received 7 upvotes, he posted an answer and I've seen a lot of cases like that. I didn't mean to upset you, I was just clarifying the point I made, that sometimes it's possible to convert the comment to an answer without warnings. Sorry if my comment was a bit harsh, It wasn't targeted to high-level mathematicians like you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: FWIW, your comment to the other answer made me sad as well!

Comment: How much time do I have to spare? It's not at all constant - I'm a math phd student. Sometimes I'm really busy, other times I'm without inspiration. But I've been a site regular for the last year, and I plan on being one for the coming year too. *Answers in Comments* I don't think it's a moderator's place intervene. I'd leave a comment...

Comment: (continued)... In fact, I think Arturo does this a lot, probably because his bar for an 'acceptable answer' seems to be pretty high (that is, I think his answers are exceptional). I commented to him (just him), e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/126749/9754) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/74665/9754). In general, I like how this site currently runs, and I think I'd fit in nicely. Conceivably, it's very tumultuous behind the curtain, but it seems that the site runs pretty smoothly (now). I think I'd work with them just fine.

Comment: (oops - I missed one): And I leave partial answers all the time. Sometimes, they're the only answer. Sometimes, the OP asks for details in the comments. Or other users. Others sometimes do the same; or they don't, and they give the full answer. This is another case where I don't think the mods intervene. I certainly wouldn't edit out details from a question. But in the past, I have been annoyed when some of us answered a question in hints and someone else wrote an explicit description. So I did what I think any member of the community would do: I wrote a comment. And that's still what I'd do.

Comment: @Phira I'm in second year undergraduate so sometimes I am busy like crazy, other times I am like my brain is like a dry well. Most of the time I'm doing some maths related thing, which usually means being on here. One can see that I am pretty active on Math.SE; I have been on this site for 300+ days now, almost a year! I personally think that if people leave answers in comments that depends, it is usually difficult to determine when a comment is *actually* that leads to an eventual solution/proof. However if it is obvious to me that the comment does lead to a full proof ....

Comment: @Phira Then preferably I would like to migrate that comment to an answer, simply because the person that typed up that comment can explain a little more. However, I would leave it up to the person that left the comment to do that. Similarly for short answers. I would like to intervene in someone's personal choice.

Comment: @Phira As for our current mods, I once had an issue with some person downvoting many posts on Math.SE. I sent Zev and email and almost immediately got a reply from him and he corrected the situation, I think that would be an example that I would like to emulate!

Answer (score 8):

**Question for Moderator Candidates:**

Has your account on Math.SE ever been suspended?  How many times?  What were the circumstances of your suspension, and why do you think that your behavior will improve once you are given greater authority?

Obviously, suspensions and the circumstances for suspensions are generally not publicly discussed; however, I think once a user nominates themselves for a moderator position the community has some right to get an explanation for behavior that warranted a suspension.

Comment: Yes, once. Since I'm active in MSE chat room, I once got into an argument with a user who called me "he" despite he knew I'm female. I got offended and made a remark and a 30 minutes chat suspension afterwards. I don't want to vindicate it but I think I needed an experience like that. I'll try my best to be reasonable and avoid getting into an argument like that but in a case it happens again, I'll take some pills to control my temper! =)

Comment: No, mine has never been suspended.

Comment: @Gigili: Aspirin is just a blood thinner. You might want to try something that will actually help you relax.

Comment: So, the candidates can arm twist facts? And, nobody should clarify that the statements here are not true?

Comment: @KannappanSampath Obviously, a lot of posts are already missing from this conversation, but I have to inform you that no, "he" is not a general reference to an unknown person.

Comment: @KannappanSampath, Gigili: can you please remove these comments and maybe replace them by something less inflamed? There is no need to retrace history *here*.

Comment: @KannappanSampath However unappropriate the situation was, I don't think it should be brought up here.

Comment: @Mariano I have obliged. And, I am willing to see the same from Gigili.

Comment: @Peter So, I should shut my mouth whenever she pokes needle into my mouth? I don't understand your logic. Regards,

Comment: NO,my account has not been suspended , ever.

Comment: @KannappanSampath I think you should stand up for yourself, but elswhere.

Answer (score 8):

*(This is not an official announcement)*

---

It looks as though **Bill Dubuque** and **Eric Naslund** were elected. Just wanted to upload this for those who aren't active on chat.

Zhen Lin posted his computations: http://pastebin.com/xRtnG2wq
Not sure if these are identical, but Bill uploaded more: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stphi.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the information @TheChaz. I think you should post this as a new post instead.

Comment: @Marvis: I get the sense that there are official protocols for identifying those elected, and notifying them/the *hoi polloi*. Just wanted to put up a stopgap without stepping on too many toes...

Comment: Congratulations @BillDubuque

Comment: Congratulations @EricNaslund

Comment: Thanks for the preliminary results. These were available as raw data at 20:00 UTC, but the processed results are now available [here](http://elections.stackexchange.com/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/election/3)

Comment: @robjohn Bad luck! You were one among my three candidates. You should definitely contest the next time as well! Good luck next time!

Comment: Congrats to Bill and Eric. Good luck! Just one general question. How was the outcome decided? The numbers on the transcript are mostly Greek to me :-) It would not have changed my votes, but it would have been nice to have seen a description of the algorithm in advance. Why was this bit left out? I still couldn't find it from any official SE page. Without an explanation I would have expected something like: 3 votes to 1st pick, 2 to the 2nd, one to the 3rd. A big minus to the system for not automatically giving a link to an explanation.

Comment: @Jyrki: (a link to the wiki page of) the method of tabulation was available on the sidebar of the main election page (linked in the OP above). Meeks method, or something like that. This was discussed/confirmed in chat as said users were posting the calculations.

Answer (score 6):

**Question to Moderator Candidates:** Are you also active on MathOverflow? Are you active on Meta there?

The two sites are somewhat connected and I quite like that. There are also often discussion on MO-Meta about problematic behaviors of users active at both sites. I think this is relevant information for MO-moderators.

**ETA**: As a response to some comments that don't see any way in which being on MO or MO-Meta could impact moderation of Math.SE I thought I would add some concrete examples as to why it might be helpful for moderators here to be involved on MO, particularly MO-Meta.

First, MO and math.SE are overlapping communities, and as such have many overlapping users and problems.  Sometimes being aware of a problem user or question from MO-Meta can help the moderators here be more vigilant with respect to that user or question on math.SE.  Also some system problems crop up in both places, and more information in such situations is always better.  Some examples from MO-Meta:

[On chrome crashing on math.SE and MO](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1336/chrome-crash/) 
[On a problematic user/question](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1213/help-in-figuring-out-my-problem/) 
[Overlapping problematic behavior on both math.SE and MO](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1187/extending-from-a-plane-in-r3-again-and-again-and-again/)

There are many more such examples if one wants to search the comments on MO-Meta for "math.SE" or "MSE".

In addition to helping the moderators become aware of potential problems earlier, some high rep math.SE users and moderators have, I would say, been "unofficial spokespeople" for the math.SE community.  This is obviously above and beyond moderation duties, but is a very nice thing for them to have done and helps the math.SE community (and its moderation) by making sure MO is referring the right sorts of questions here, and in the right way.  Two great examples of such posts on MO-Meta:

[On trying to send people to math.SE in the "right" way](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1125/sending-people-to-math-stack-exchange) 
[On cross-posted questions](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/943/rfc-policy-about-crossposting-and-reposting-from-mse/)

I hope these examples illustrate some of the benefits the math.SE community has derived from having moderators here be aware of what is going on at MO and MO-Meta.  Of course, being a research mathematician certainly shouldn't be a prerequisite for being a moderator of math.SE, but there are solid reasons to ask the question about activity on that site in particular.

Comment: Yes, good question. I know at least two current moderators actively participate meta.MO and I suppose they can carry the word over if needed.

Comment: I browse MO quite a bit, but I haven't been an active participant, unfortunately. But as I delve deeper into my studies, I suspect that I will be using it more.

Comment: I am not a member of MathOverflow; however, I have frequently read posts on MO and on meta.MO. However, as it might be informative not only regarding users with problem behaviors, but also regarding topics related to site moderation, it would seem to be a good idea for any math.SE moderator to join MO.

Comment: I don't see how this might help one moderating MSE.

Comment: One can't help but wonder if the ever-charming Princess @Gigili is responsible for the lone downvote on 3 of the 4 "answers" here... you don't like me, you argued with Asaf, and you don't see the benefit of being an MO user !

Comment: @rar: That makes perfect sense. But it goes beyond the moderating role, as you said.

Comment: @TheChaz: On meta, I simply downvote when I disagree, I suppose it's how it works.

Comment: @Gigili I guess I shouldn't have deleted that comment now that you've responded to it.  I don't seem to have any way to undelete it, however.  Sorry.

Comment: I have a mathoverflow account but I am not active on there.

Comment: @rar: No problem at all. I just wanted to thank you for the great explanation. I made an account there and will try to be active.

Comment: I'm not active on MO because I'm not a research mathematician. I have an account, which I used before I knew of the existence of M.SE, but quickly transitioned to using M.SE as a more appropriate forum for the kind of mathematics that I want to discuss. The two sites have different aims, participants and cultures. It is common that questions on MO should be moved to M.SE (so there is benefit to an MO moderator being familiar with M.SE) but the flow rarely goes in the other direction. It's possible that problematic users will use both sites though, so I would check Meta.MO if I was a moderator.

Comment: @TheChaz - I think that not being afraid of an argument is a great attribute for a moderator to have.  Sometimes, it is necessary for a moderator to show his/her teeth, as well as to be able to justify his/her position.  And let's face it, Asaf badly needed someone to argue with him, after all that talk of nuclear domination.  Also, I don't understand how being an MO user would help a moderator here; Gigili is a user of many other sites, so she's perfectly well aware of the principles of moderation.  The fact that she's not a research-level mathematician is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @TheChaz and honestly, after your sarcastic remarks about charming princesses, I wouldn't be too surprised if Gigili doesn't like you much.  The fact that she has spoken up so vocally here makes me far more inclined to support her candidacy than if she had just lain back and sucked up all the vitriol that has been directed at her.  After everything that's happened here, I admire her backbone immensely.  I will undoubtedly be voting for her once the election begins.

Comment: My concern when I hear about meta.MO being used to discuss things happening on math.SE is [things like this](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/598/is-metamathstackexchange-ask-question-broken/#Item_9) and [this](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/782/3/trouble-at-mathse/).

Comment: @David: Surprisingly, I find myself in total agreement with your first comment (though I meant my comment about MO/lack thereof to be evidence of a downvote only). I confess to playing the antagonist with the Harbinger of Pleasantry, but am concerned with... well, I'll save it for the primary :)

Comment: FWIW I upvoted this answer, too. Something that the candidates should know about, and certainly me the voter likes to hear about. BUT a nominee, who is not a research mathematician, should not register at MO as a response to this question. IMHO that is quite the wrong reaction.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I am free to register, How you say I should not? I registered to check it out and see what's going on there.

Comment: @Gigili, it does look like I jumped to a conclusion without thinking about alternatives. I apologize for that.

Comment: Quite all right, @JyrkiLahtonen, don't worry about it.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I am actually offended by your comment. I'm not always in search for an argument, this is not my drug. Please delete that comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm sorry, but I did not mean you any offence.  However, I do stand by my comment.  If you want it deleted, then flag it for moderator attention.  I will not delete it myself.

Comment: @rar I am not active on mathoverflow, but I have seen several MO-meta threads on a certain user that has been posting a lot of questions about the Birch and Swinnerton Dyer Conjecture, Tate - Shafarevich group etc. I am aware that that user is also here on Math.SE. However I don't think that there has been such a big thing going on about this user here as there has been on MO.

Comment: @BenjaminLim: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3584/re-opening-a-question) thread on meta shows that many users on M.SE share the perspective if the majority on MO. Also, I'm not sure that everything thi user did i visible, I believe some of his questions were deleted.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker With regards to that user, I think I would personally send him an email and ask him to please try and improve the quality of his questions and stop all the flattery. In fact in the past I have tried  to give him advice on how to go on with his studies. He has responded well and I think one can see that the quality of his questions has gone up.

Comment: No, I am not active in MathOverflow as of yet. but I do go there when I need to dive into something deep in maths.

Answer (score 4):

Since it is more organized, and I am one of the last people to nominate themselves, I am posting my answers here:

> How much time do you have to spare and have you thought about whether you are really willing to continue this effort over a long time period?

Hopefully my participation up to present will answer this question:  So far, I having been using the site consistently for the last 15 months, averaging a post a day and reading many more.  During this time I have also participated actively on Meta, frequently commenting and visiting the site, and averaging a post every two weeks.

> What is your stance on "answers in comments" that leave lots of unanswered questions and their flip-side, the "incomplete hint answers"?

For answers in comments, I don't think this is a problem unless the answer in the comments discourages people from posting any answer at all, leaving the question "unanswered."  In this case, I agree with Rahul Narain's proposal in this old meta thread: [Dealing with answers in comments.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments)
I personally have not noticed the problem of "incomplete hint answers" as from my experience, the answer writer will often modify their post after receiving a confused comment from the OP.  I don't think any type of answers should be outright discouraged.  Hints have their place, and so do complete solutions.

> Have you looked at the behaviour and style of the current moderators and do you think that you could cooperate well with them?

Yes.

> In Which Time Zone are you?

I currently live in Paris, UTC+2, but will be returning to Vancouver, UTC-7, in August.  It is worth noting that in November Vancouver returns to standard time (from daylight savings) which is UTC-8.

> Are you also active on MathOverflow? Are you active on Meta there?

I frequently use Math Overflow, and browse several of the tags daily; [here is my account.](https://mathoverflow.net/users/12176/eric-naslund)  I also read the meta posts, but I am not interested in participating in the meta there for several reasons.

> (To those whose flag weight is less than 50) In all the time active on the site, why did you not raise many flags? How do you think you will handle this shift from not-flagging to clear flags?

I have usually tried to deal with problematic posts in one of the many ways which are open to top users.  Often leaving a comment for the OP can be very constructive.  There are however some cases where flagging is important, and I have occasionally come across this and appropriately flagged.

> (To all) What is your stand on the CW policy? Do you agree or disagree that most big list and soft questions should be turned CW?

I think it depends on the question, but I am more inclined to make soft questions CW.  What I believe is most important is having a consistent standard.

> Has your account on Math.SE ever been suspended?

No, never.

Answer (score 1):

First round of answers:

> *(To those whose flag weight is less than 50) In all the time active on the site, why did you not raise many flags? How do you think you will handle this shift from not-flagging to clear flags?* - Asaf Karagila

I tended to comment on the mishap rather than flag, since the system was alien to me. However, when I discovered the system, I flagged *and* commented on problematic situations. When it comes to questions, I tend to vote to close rather than flagging, since it saves the mods some time.

> *(To all) What is your stand on the CW policy? Do you agree or disagree that most big list and soft questions should be turned CW?* - Asaf Karagila

I agree that most big list and soft questions should be CW. The latter tend to get votes steming from subjectivity and the former is just a compendium The votes should serve to order the questions as the community sees fit. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138112/what-does-it-really-mean-for-something-to-be-trivial) how I got simply +1 and another user got +6, but the OP chose my question (please avoid voting when visiting the link, I don't want any complaints of propaganda). It is simply subjective.

**How much time do you have to spare and have you thought about whether you are really willing to continue this effort over a long time period?**

I have a nice deal of time to spare. However, since I'm in University, there will be times I'll be studying for exams. I don't think being a moderator is too hard of an effort, so I think I will be able to continue participating.

**What is your stance on "answers in comments" that leave lots of unanswered questions and their flip-side, the "incomplete hint answers"?**

Both are useful. Why? They help the OP to think. They don't serve the full dish, so it (hopefully) motivates the OP in trying to work on his own. The hint comments do no harm, and are usually upvoted by the community. As for questions, they have to be well thought out. Usually, the good **hint** answers come from high rep users who can produce such useful hints. I see a small problematic in new users that tend to answer with a comment, saying "Use this and that", but produce low quality hints. These can be either made a comment or deleted altogether, depending on their quality.

**Have you looked at the behaviour and style of the current moderators and do you think that you could cooperate well with them?**

I have. However, since I am not part of the team, I will have to get to know their ways and preferences, and this can be only achieved with some time of work.

**Question to Moderator Candidates**: Are you also active on MathOverflow? Are you active on Meta there? I am not active. I'm a freshman university student in mathematics.

**Question to Moderator Candidates**: In Which Time Zone are you? I'm in UTC -3.00.

Answer (score -1):

**Question to moderator candidates**

The [election statistics page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/) (click "Mathematics") lists some statistics, including:

- Number of answers/questions (on both main and meta)
- Reputation (total, per post, per day)
- Badges (number of gold, silver, as well as "Yes/no" for "Noteworthy badges")

<strike>The nomination page also lists the number of helpful flags of each candidate.</strike> (*Asaf has now written an entire question about this, so I'll defer to that*)

> $1.$ Which of these statistics do you think is most important for determining if a candidate is qualified to be a moderator? Least important?
>
> $2.$ 
>   Are there other objective/quantifiable qualities that the community should look for in the candidates?
>
> $3.$ Are you "weak" (numerically) in any important areas? What are your thoughts on this area(s) as it relates to you specifically?
>
> $4.$ On a scale of $1 - 10$ (low to high), how proud of you will your mother/maternal figure be if you are elected?

Comment: The fourth one should not be a question here.

Comment: @Eric: *"Should"??* Maybe not. I find the fourth point of Saurav's nomination endearing, and thought it funny to include. Feel free to not answer it.

Comment: It is endearing, my comment was a bit harsh, but I don't think there is a strong connection between $4$ and choosing who would best moderator Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Eric: Agreed. ${}{}$

Comment: in response to question number 4, a sure 10. :-)

Comment: @EricNaslund, The Chaz's humorousness and informality is a nice and balancing touch to some of the more serious-toned users here. Don't think anything was meant by it. :)

Comment: @Limitless: Maybe I went too far... none of the candidates have felt the need to answer any of the first three questions! I chalk this (and other seemingly negative experiences that I have on MSE) up to the "jackass" persona that I have carefully crafted over the past year.

Comment: @TheChaz, very possible. However, I see purpose in your questions. I do not know about their intentions with respect to not answering your questions.

Comment: Re: 2: I would advise the community to vote for the candidates that they think will be most effective solving the major issues challenging the site, esp. dealing with tension over contentious meta issues. These are often the things that can cause a general math forum to crash and burn. Conversely, the quicker such issues are resolved, the smoother the main site will grow, and the easier it will be to attract further knowledgeable members.