# Questions that have been answered in comments

Tags: discussion, comment, answers, unanswered-questions

I have noticed an abundance of questions on the main site that have no answers, but have been answered in comments, often "accepted" with a comment such as "Thanks a lot!". Such questions bog down the "Unanswered" tab, and cause some confusion when users browsing that tab in search for questions to answer come across them. Is there anything to be done about these questions?

Comment: A feature request means you identified a software change that would solve some problem, and are asking for this specific change to be made. "Is there anything to be done?" is not a feature request.

Comment: I was requesting a hypothetical feature that could be added to solve that problem. Also, the tag wiki excerpt didn't say anything suggesting that the tag shouldn't be used for this question.