# Answering in the comments

Tags: discussion, comment, answers

I have this question its mine [(my question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526368/linearity-of-first-ode-a-first-course-in-differential-equations-with-modeling-a) Its not the first time that people answer in the comments, I know that the unanswered questions impact the site statistics, and if I answer it using the comments my reputation. What do I do about this answering in comments? It's not that I want to say the person is bad but its happened twice already.

Comment: Excellent question to ask.  Feel free to answer this, referring to the comment, if it helped you. You asked a good question, and deserve an actual answer in an answer field.

Comment: Please also see [this question about "answering in comments"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments?r=SearchResults&s=2|55.3622).

Comment: I deleted my comment and posted an answer. EnlightenedFunky

Comment: Seems to be the same here in this question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can always flag for moderator attention. I think this is reasonable if your question is involved and an answer involves more than a short sentence.

Comment: I don't think this is a great idea - there's not much a moderator can do to remedy answers in comments. They could leave a comment directed at the user who answered in the comments, but anyone with 50+ reputation could do that - and the extra "weight" of a moderator's comment is probably unnecessary unless the user has a pattern of this. They could delete the comment, but that seems counterproductive. They could write an answer based on the comment, but anyone could do that. The more punitive moderator powers are irrelevant unless the given user is somehow using comments to abuse the system.

Comment: @Milo: answering in the comments is so widespread in Math.SE that even moderators do it. So I doubt they will do anything about it.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Deleting the comment makes the most sense. Some moderators do it, others don't. Flagging for a moderator is basically the only possibility to address the problem, to my knowledge.