# Follow-up on previous question about comment-answered questions

Tags: discussion, comment, answers

Last week I asked this [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35479/treatment-of-comment-answered-questions-what-is-the-current-policy-as-of-februa?cb=1) on what the current policy is on comment-answered questions.

I thought I had reached an understanding. The top answers expressed that if someone sees this, they should post an answer directly addressing the question, *even if the answer was short enough to post in comments.*

However, I did so under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191854/if-0a-b-c-d1-then-how-do-i-prove-the-following-inequality-abcd1/4640115?noredirect=1#comment9793200_4640115) and it got reported for being a low-quality post. This is really frustrating.

[image]

Maybe I misunderstood the answers of my original question, in which case I would like to understand what I missed about the policy. On the other hand, if there is a stark division among Math SE members on how to address this issue, a new user posting a meta post about is is NOT going to solve the issue and something greater must be done. I think this problem has gone on far too long to be left unresolved...

Comment: People should keep in mind that this poorly-reviewed answer was on an "is my proof correct?" question, where "Yes, this looks good." is a valid answer. But I think it makes for a fairly poor test case for ClydeKertzler's greater question, as "is my proof correct?" questions have a pretty ambiguous status already, with many users expressing the belief that they don't fit the site well, and that they generally produce low-quality answers, even at their best.

Comment: I think questions like "is my solution correct?" can only have  good answers if the solution is not correct, or at least can be improved.

Comment: If the OP's self-attempt is correct and remarkable (i.e., worth keeping), then I would encourage them to post it as a self-answer. If it is correct but arguably adds no value to the site, then it should hopefully eventually be closed/deleted/self-deleted, and I think posting an answer obstructs this? +1 to @Jonathan's comment.

Comment: @kludg Which is why many of us feel that "is my solution correct?" questions are generally a poor fit for this site.  For example, the question being discussed here is, mathematically, a duplicate of another question.  Does the argument in the question really make it a different question?

Comment: What many users do, Clyde, is mark the small square in the right hand bottom corner of the answer field "Community Wiki".  It's a way to have an answer present, while acknowledging that you are not seeking unearned reputation.  Perhaps a suggestion for you, down the road.

Comment: @amWhy [The community wiki (CW) button should not be used for reputation denial.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227290/)  Moreover, I don't think that it is productive to frame this conversation in terms of "unearned reputation".  Rather, I think it is helpful to consider the set of circumstances which makes "Yes, that looks good!" a valid answer to a question---if such an answer is sufficient, then the question probably doesn't fit well with the SE model, and should be modified or closed.  For example, the question here is, really, a duplicate.

Comment: It's a viable option, to post as CW, which invites others to add other suggestions. ...which is what Community Wiki intends.  The descriptive use of CW pertains to my first comment (how it is used in practice.) The prescriptive sense you propose, is fulfilled as well, @Xander.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I don't think this link (also posted in the comments to the other question) is a good reference here. This was mostly about questions being converted to CW by the system under certain circumstances, not about users converting their own questions to CW. So I don't think any community consensus on the latter practice can be deduced from the reactions to this question.

Comment: I agree with amWhy that this use of CW is reasonable. If I convert someone else's comment into an answer, I certainly want to invite them to edit it for improvement if they like. [I also agree with you, Xander, that it's beside the point for this particular question. "Yes, that looks good!" is not a valid answer, whether CW or not.]