# Suggestion for dealing with a comment if it contain the Answer to the question (w/o other answers)

Tags: feature-request, comment, answers, flagging, best-practices

**Suggestion for dealing with a comment if it contain the Answer to the question (w/o other answers)**

If I try to flag a comment there are the following alternatives: harassment / unfriendly / obsolete / others: in this last alternative, I would like to suggest that you could make possible to give an explanation of why I think that the comment it is truly an answer instead of just a comment, such a **Moderator could take the comment and uploading it as an answer (if he share my opinion), keeping as author the original poster**.

I think it is an easy alternative that will solve many, of the MANY open question without answers since the are solved in the first comment.

It's really common to see first comments were the question got answered, so the question are left open without answers (since it already have it in the comment section). I think this generate two issues: question are left open, and most important, since the comments got outside from the voting system they cannot receive downvotes (which sometimes are useful for incomplete or partially mistaken answers). And on the other hand, copy the comment by myself into an answer section felt dishonest so I don't think is an option, and probably other users will downvote it as plagiarism distorting the validity of the answer itself.

I left here my humble suggestion.

Comment: Comments cannot be turned into answers.  Feel free to flag such comments for deletion.  If the comments are in reply to questions which otherwise meet site standards, feel free to post an answer yourself.  Yes, I am posting an answer in a comment.  Because I know that this has come up before, and my next step is to find a dupe.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank for the comment. I visited the mention question before but it were to many opinions and don't get what we could do about it. I am going to modify the question as a suggestion only, but is not possible just keep it closed.

Comment: the suggestion could be posted as an answer in the linked duplicate.

Comment: You can have a look at this discussion: [Dealing with answers in comments.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1559) And maybe at [other related posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1559).

Comment: On [meta.se], you can find several related feature requests - some of them already marked (status-declined): [Add a feature to migrate a comment into an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100729), [Way to convert a comment to an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77110), [Allow converting comments to answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51899), [Mark a comment as the answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1555), etc.