# What should we do if a correct answer is just in the comments section?

Tags: discussion, comment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should one do when one’s question has been answered in the comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments)

For example I post plenty of questions that get some really good clear answers. However, people often times leave them in the comments section where you cant select the "correct" answer. I always upvote them, but I feel bad because I'm not selecting someone elses answer who actually posted their answer in the answers section. Should I just select an answer thats in the answers section just to select a right answer?

Answer (score 2):

Ask the author of the comment to post it as an answer so that you can accept it.